# Microsoft Excel 2010, reference external *.csv data into table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have multiple *.csv files with rows of data being added periodically.

I want to have all of this data be referenced in a table in an Excel 2010 worksheet.  If data is updated/added to the *.csv, the Excel table needs to update as well.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

A simple idea is to use "Paste Link(N)" option. Do a copy of portion of cells from *.csv file (area of cells which are needs to be replicated) and paste the same portion of cells using "Paste Link(N)" option (mouse right click) in the excel sheet (area of cells where the auto replication should happen). This will ensure all your changes in the *.csv file automatically changed to the corresponding cells in the excel file.

Note: Cell format must be same in both *.csv and excel sheet in case if Date and time is going to be updated.

[image]

Hope this helps.